# How can I tell if a file's been renamed?

Tags: vb6, filesystems

I'm updating some legacy code to more efficiently use `.ini` files for parameter storage. Basically, it caches all the settings internally once they're read so that they can be read again without opening the file. Before using the cache, I compare the cache creation time to the last modified time of the file, and recreate the cache with the updated file. This works great, except when users rename files, because that action doesn't update the last modified time.

So if I copy my `app.ini` to `app - copy.ini`, modify `app - copy.ini` outside of my program, then delete `app.ini` and rename the copy to `app.ini`, my program is now using an outdated cache. Even if my program caught the deletion of `app.ini` and cleared the cache, it would not rebuild the cache when the copy was renamed. The program is designed to run for a very long time unattended, so I would like to avoid continually monitoring the file - only check it once I need to read a parameter.

Comment: Presumably you've checked that this will really achieve a performance boost that the users will consider worthwile?

Comment: @MarkJ - No, not yet. I just wrote the caching code, and will be testing for performance gains shortly. It was mostly an exercise to re-familiarize myself with VB6, but if it leads to performance gains, awesome. But my main question was about detecting renamed files - the specific application is just an example. A file watcher probably solves the problem, but doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: "NTFS delays updates to the last access time for a file by up to one hour after the last access."  That's because these timestamps are meant to be low-volatility attributes to reduce filesystem overhead.  INI files are not meant to be highly volitile themselves, which makes hand-editing externally feasible.  If you need tighter control over the process you should provide a Settings UI to a file users don't modify directly.  Then you can use your own high-volitility timestamps within the data if required, in a controlled manner.  Rely on system-level file caching for performance.

Comment: Last access time is disabled by default on Vista and later --http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2006/11/07/disabling-last-access-time-in-windows-vista-to-improve-ntfs-performance.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are needing is a filewatcher for vb6, you could try it by interop with .net or use something like this [VB6 Implementation](http://www.thescarms.com/vbasic/FolderSpy.aspx)

Comment: I think this is what I'll do. It'd still be nice to know if I can detect a change in the file using its attributes, tho.

Comment: You may want to try looking at the archive attribute, it is turned on when the file has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

For that scenario, you could keep a hash of the contents of each `.ini` file the program is using and periodically check each file. If the hash is different than what it was last time you checked, then it's contents were changed or it's a different file caused by this rename scenario.

Comment: The problem with this is that I'm trying to boost performance by not opening the file every time I need to retrieve a setting. Doing a hash on the entire thing would not be a good solution for that.